# How to make different dataframes of different lengths become equal in length (downsampling and upsampling)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation, resampling

I have many dataframes (timeseries) that are of different lengths ranging between 28 and 179. I need to make them all of length 104. (upsampling those below 104 and downsampling those above 104)

For upsampling, the linear method can be sufficient to my needs. For downsampling, the mean of the values should be good.

To get all files to be the same length, I thought that I need to make all dataframes start and end at the same dates.

I was able to downsample all to the size of the smallest dataframe (i.e. 28) using below lines of code:

```
df.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1991' ,periods=len(df), end='1/1/2000'), inplace=True)

resampled=df.resample('120D').mean()
```

However, this will not give me good results when I feed them into the model I need them for as it shrinks the longer files so much thus distorting the data.

This is what I tried so far:

```
df.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1991' ,periods=len(df), end='1/1/2000'), inplace=True)

if df.shape[0]>100: resampled=df.resample('D').mean()

elif df.shape[0]<100: resampled=df.astype(float).resample('33D').interpolate(axis=0, method='linear')

else: break
```

Now, in the above lines of code, I am getting the files to be the same length (length 100). The downsampling part works fine too.

What's not working is the **interpoaltion** on the upsampling part. It just returns dataframes of length 100 **with the first value of every column just copied over to all the rows**.

What I need is to make them all size 104 (average size). This means any df of length>104 needs to downsampled and any df of length<104 needs to be upsampled.

As an example, please consider the two dfs as follows:

```
>>df1

index                                                                 
0       3   -1    0            
1       5   -3    2          
2       9   -5    0 
3      11   -7   -2     

>>df2

index                                                                 
0       3   -1    0            
1       5   -3    2          
2       9   -5    0
3       6   -3   -2
4       4    0   -4
5       8    2   -6
6      10    4   -8
7      12    6   -10
```

Suppose the avg length is 6, **the expected output would be**:

**df1 upsampled** to length 6 using interpolation - for e.g. `resamle(rule).interpolate()`.

And **df2 downsampled** to length 6 using `resample(rule).mean()` .

**Update:**

If I could get all the files to be upsampled to 179, that would be fine as well.

Comment: I think that pandas Groupby might help here but I am new to python and I don't know how exactly I can apply it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the problem is when you do `resample` in the up-sampling case, the other values are not kept. With you example df1, you can see it by using `asfreq` on one column:

```
print (df1.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1991' ,periods=len(df1), end='1/1/2000'))[1]
          .resample('33D').asfreq().isna().sum(0))
#99 rows are nan on the 100 length resampled dataframe
```

So when you do `interpolate` instead of `asfreq`, it actually interpolates with just the first value, meaning that the first value is "repeated" over all the rows

To get the result you want, then before interpolating, use also `mean` even in the up-sampling case, such as:

```
print (df1.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1991' ,periods=len(df1), end='1/1/2000'))[1]
          .resample('33D').mean().interpolate().head())
1991-01-01    3.000000
1991-02-03    3.060606
1991-03-08    3.121212
1991-04-10    3.181818
1991-05-13    3.242424
Freq: 33D, Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

and you will get values as you want.

To conclude, I think in both up-sampling and down-sampling cases, you can use the same command

```
resampled = (df.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1991' ,periods=len(df), end='1/1/2000'))
               .resample('33D').mean().interpolate())
```

Because the `interpolate` would not affect the result in the down-sampling case.

Comment: Eventually I used: `resampled=(df.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1991' ,periods=len(df), end='30/3/1991'))
               .resample('20H').mean().interpolate())`. Yields the same result really (except the length yielded with these dates and rule is 106). The date range just seemed more sensible.

Comment: @R.A sorry I'm not following, the same result as? I see you change the date_range and the resample value, but you mean the method does not work with these settings?

Comment: It gives the same results as in it also performs correct upsampling & downsampling. Meaning that the change of start and end dates doesn't really affect the end result very much. The changed dates just made more sense because the longest length of my files was 179.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my version using skimage.transform.resize() function:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'a': [3,5,9,11],
                    'b': [-1,-3,-5,-7],
                    'c': [0,2,0,-2]
                   })
df1

    a   b   c
0   3   -1  0
1   5   -3  2
2   9   -5  0
3   11  -7  -2


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize

def df_resample(df1, num=1):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    for key, value in df1.iteritems(): 
        temp = value.to_numpy()/value.abs().max() # normalize
        resampled = resize(temp, (num,1), mode='edge')*value.abs().max() # de-normalize
        df2[key] = resampled.flatten().round(2)
    return df2


df2 = df_resample(df1, 20) # resampling rate is 20
df2

    a   b   c
0   3.0     -1.0    0.0
1   3.0     -1.0    0.0
2   3.0     -1.0    0.0
3   3.4     -1.4    0.4
4   3.8     -1.8    0.8
5   4.2     -2.2    1.2
6   4.6     -2.6    1.6
7   5.0     -3.0    2.0
8   5.8     -3.4    1.6
9   6.6     -3.8    1.2
10  7.4     -4.2    0.8
11  8.2     -4.6    0.4
12  9.0     -5.0    0.0
13  9.4     -5.4    -0.4
14  9.8     -5.8    -0.8
15  10.2    -6.2    -1.2
16  10.6    -6.6    -1.6
17  11.0    -7.0    -2.0
18  11.0    -7.0    -2.0
19  11.0    -7.0    -2.0
```